# Power BI: a visualization to dynamically show a network interaction

Tags: graph, powerbi, data-science, data-visualization

Network visual with dynamic selection

Is anyone aware of a network association visual with dynamic selection formatting? Essentially, something like network navigator (or zoom charts drill down graph pro) but with the ability to select nodes and have associated nodes highlighted in some way. I’ve not been able to find this functionality using the zoom charts free trial or with any other visual. TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have basic knowledge of Python, here's a solution based on [NetworkX](https://networkx.org) for creating a graph and [gravis](https://robert-haas.github.io/gravis-docs) for creating an interactive graph visualization where you can highlight the neighborhood of a node by hovering with the mouse over it.

Disclosure: I'm the author of gravis. I hope this concrete example is useful for your requirements.

```
import gravis as gv
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.les_miserables_graph()
gv.d3(graph, edge_size_data_source='weight', use_edge_size_normalization=True, node_hover_neighborhood=True)
```

Result if you use this code inside a Jupyter notebook and hover over the node `Myriel`. You can also use a regular Python interpreter and see the visualization in a webbrowser window that pops up.

[image]